# unresolved import 'ploty' ; unresolved import 'plotly.gragh_objs'

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I`m making a 'Rolling Dice' project with Plotly. before that,  I install Plotly using the command:
$ python -m pip install --user plotly

When  I run 'from plotly.gragh_objs import Bar, layout', I got the error message:
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.gragh_objs''

I try to upgrade pip, but it doesn`t work. anyone know where are the problems.

My code as follow:

```
from plotly.gragh_objs import Bar, Layout
from ploty import offline

from dice import Die

die = Die()
results = []
for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

frequencies = []
for value in range(1, die.num_sides+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

x_values = list(range(1, die.num_sides+1))
data = [Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)]

x_axis_config = {'title':'Result'}
y_axis_config = {'title':'Frequency of Result'}
my_layout = Layout(title='Results of rolling one D6 1000 times',
xaxis=x_axis_config, yaxis=y_axis_config)
offline.plot({'data':data, 'layout':my_layout}, filename='d6.html')
```

Comment: Seems like I spell 'plotly' wrong in the second line of my code.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like pycharm?

Comment: This is how I usually write it. Misspelling? `import plotly.graph_objects as go`.

Comment: I followed the book Python crash course`s instruction, "from plotly.gragh_objs import Bar, Layout" but it turns out the  "plotly.grgh_objs"  the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import code should be as follows:

```
from plotly.graph_objects import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline
```